# I am using a product room and storing Firestore data in a list and then implementing search on that list but I am getting empty array as search result

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
package ml.daily.basket;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import ml.daily.basket.data.Product;

public class search extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CollectionReference collectionReference;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SearchView searchView;
    private verticalProductScrollAdapter adapter;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private List<Product> productData=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.search_Results);
        searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        getData();

        if (searchView!=null){
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SEARCH " + query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    searchUsers(query);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SEARCH " + newText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    searchUsers(newText);
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }


    }
```

This method gets products from Firebase but in the log, I am getting an empty array.

```
    private void getData(){
        db.collection("milk").whereEqualTo("milk",1).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
               if (error != null){
                   System.err.println("Listen failed:" + error);
                   return;
               }
                Log.d("ds", value + " => ");
               for (DocumentSnapshot doc: value){
                   Product product = doc.toObject(Product.class);
                   productData.add(product);
               }
                updateProduct(productData);
            }
        });
    }

    private void searchUsers(String recherche) {
        if (recherche.length() > 0)
            recherche = recherche.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + recherche.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        List<Product> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Product product : productData){
            if(product.getProductName() != null && product.getProductName().contains(recherche)){
                results.add(product);
            }
        }
        updateProduct(results);
    }
```

To set the updated product in the recycler view.

```
    private void updateProduct(List<Product> productData) {

        //Sort the list by id

        Collections.sort(productData, new Comparator<Product>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
                int res = -1;
                if (o1.getId() > (o2.getId())) {
                    res = 1;
                }
                return res;
            }
        });
        Log.d("search is", String.valueOf(productData));
    }

    

}
```

Comment: In the line `Product product = doc.toObject(Product.class);` are you getting some value?

Comment: Yes I made some changes and now I am able to search but I am not able to show it in recycler view as per already created room. Means I am not able to show the searched product getting some binding issue.